# how to find a and b in this function of the form f(p) = (a.p + b) mod 2, knowing that plain text + cipher text are given (Brute Force)

Tags: java, encryption, key, public-key-encryption, discrete-mathematics

this is the question 
Breaking code Brute force is an important, and basic, algorithmic paradigm. In a brute-force algorithm, a problem is solved in the most straightforward manner based on the statement of the problem and the deﬁnitions of terms. Brute-force algorithms are designed to solve problems without regard to the computing resources required, where in some you examine every possible solution until you ﬁnd one that works. Break the key (ﬁnd a and b) used for encryption using brute force, where you know plaintext and ciphertext. Assume that it has been encrypted using aﬃne ciphers  f(p) = (a.p + b).

and this is my code for, is there any other way of doing it ?

```
public static int[] findKeys(String plaintext, String ciphertext){
    int[] keys = new int[2];
    int temp, a = 0, b = 0;
    char p, c;

    for (int i = 0; i < plaintext.length(); i++) {
        p = plaintext.charAt(i);
        c = ciphertext.charAt(i);

        for (int x = 0; x <= 9; x++) {
            a = a + x;

            for (int y = 0; y <= 9; y++) {
                b = b + y;
                temp = (int) p - 65; //convert to int
                temp = Math.floorMod((a * temp + b), 26);
                p = (char) (temp + 65); //convert to char

                if (p == c) {
                    keys[0] = a;
                    keys[1] = b;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return keys;
}
```

Comment: Edit more info into your question. It's great that you've written code -- does it work? If yes, what's your question? If not, what did you expect to happen, versus what actually happens?

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are asking ... and why.  Yes obviously, there are an infinite number of "other ways" to code this.  But what are you actually looking for?  A faster way?  A simpler way?  A more elegant way? A more shiny way?   Or are you asking us to find the bugs in your code?  Or tell you if it is correct?

Comment: what I did was trying all possible numbers till I get the ones that fit and yes it works, is there other methods to ﬁnd inverse other than trying all possible numbers ?

Comment: Question doesn't make sense to me. What sets are a, b, and p from? Is the "." supposed to be multiplication? Is "f" supposed to the the encryption function? If the operation is mod 2 then you will not be able to decrypt unless "p" is a single bit and "a" is 1 mod 2. The code doesn't seem to reflect the question.